# iframe broken i IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser, fullcalendar

I have IE9 and its feature to view page in different versions is great. But i have a problem:
my page contains a iframe that loads fullcalendar (a jquery plugin). It works in IE7, Chrome and firefox, but fails in IE8 and IE9. In IE8 and IE9 the calendar is only loaded partially, only the button row on top is loaded, I cant see the actual calendar.

How come? How can i fix this?

Comment: can you submit a bug report at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/support/. please make sure to include a working demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set height=0 and width =0 to your iframe .give display-none class to that in your CSS

Comment: <iframe id="iframe" src="url/" width="0" height="0" style="display: none">, ehm... display: none usually makes everything go away